# Setting up a three tier environment in puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrant-windows, puppetlabs-apache, puppetlabs-mysql

These are my files:

1. [Nodes.pp file](https://gist.github.com/vijayboopathy/e4edf0bdc4aa0f3bce7a)
2. [site.pp file](https://gist.github.com/vijayboopathy/89a511978ec249ccb4ca)

I need to setup the infrastructure in the diagram, and I would like to use Puppet Automation in order to do so. I would need to,

1. Create 4 VMs, one for DB, 1 web server, 1 load balancer, 1 master
2. Set them up with Puppet Agent
3. Find the appropriate modules/cookbooks from the community site
   (Puppet Forge/ Chef Supermarket)
4. Configure the nodes using recipes/classes fetched from the community
   sites.
5. Provide configuration parameters in order to have all these nodes
   connect to each other.

   End goal is to have a working Wordpress setup.

I got stuck with the master agent configuration process. I have a Puppet master and 3 agents up and running. But, but whenever I run `#puppet agent --test` in the agent, It throws an error. I look forward to the community's help.

The error I am getting is...

```
[root@agent1 vagrant]# puppet agent --noop --test
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Answer (score 2):

First take a look at the puppet master logs.
Second: The error message is to short. There is missing something after the 
`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could` The text after the "Could" can be helpful ;)